Is it possible to join tables in SA360 query language? When using it with java?
I am trying to create the following query
SELECT
  customer.descriptive_name,
  customer.currency_code,
  customer.engine_id,
  customer.id,
  customer.account_type,
  campaign.bidding_strategy_type,
  campaign.end_date,
  campaign.engine_id,
  campaign.id,
  campaign.name,
  campaign.start_date,
  campaign.engine_status,
  campaign.advertising_channel_type,
  campaign.advertising_channel_sub_type,
  campaign.last_modified_time,
  campaign.creation_time,
  campaign.network_settings.target_content_network,
  campaign.network_settings.target_google_search,
  campaign.network_settings.target_partner_search_network,
  campaign.network_settings.target_search_network,
  campaign_budget.period,
  campaign_budget.delivery_method,
  campaign_budget.amount_micros,
  campaign_criterion.bid_modifier,
  campaign_criterion.device.type,
  metrics.clicks,
  metrics.cost_micros,
  metrics.impressions,
  metrics.visits,
  segments.date,
  segments.device
FROM campaign
WHERE segments.date >= '%s' AND segments.date <= '%s'


In this query i need to get data from campaign_criterion as well as campaign_labels.
Is it possible? if yes, can some one please help me with the same?
  private SearchSearchAds360StreamRequest createQueryRequest(String clientId, String query) {
    return SearchSearchAds360StreamRequest.newBuilder()
      .setCustomerId(clientId)
      .setQuery(query)
      .build();
  }

this is what i am using to create the request and this is the error i am getting.
com.google.api.gax.rpc.InvalidArgumentException: io.grpc.StatusRuntimeException: INVALID_ARGUMENT: Request contains an invalid argument.

